# Intermittent error in LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq, task-parallel-library, entity-framework-6

I have the following code in a Winforms application that is part of the code for loading and displaying data in a `DataGridView` via a `BindingSource`.

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports ForeNET.OrderMatching

Public Class frm_OrderMatching
    Private m_Context As ForeContext
    Private m_CurrentManufacturer As Byte = 0
    Private m_CurrentSeries As String = ""
    Private m_mreSeriesManfSet As ManualResetEvent
    Private m_oc_tDSR As ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction)
    Private m_tLoadQryDistributionAllOrders As Task
    Private m_tLoadSeriesManufacturer As Task

    Private Sub LoadDistributionStockRestrictionTask()
        Dim STime As DateTime = DateTime.Now, ETime As DateTime
        If Not m_CTS.Token.IsCancellationRequested Then
            DoDBContextAction(DBActivityType.Downloading, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), True, {False}, Sub() m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.Load())
            Dim Tasks As List(Of Task) = New List(Of Task)
            If m_tLoadQryDistributionAllOrders IsNot Nothing Then Tasks.Add(m_tLoadQryDistributionAllOrders)
            If m_tLoadSeriesManufacturer IsNot Nothing Then Tasks.Add(m_tLoadSeriesManufacturer)
            Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray, m_CTS.Token)
            DoDBContextAction(DBActivityType.Downloading, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), False, {True}, Sub() bs_tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.ResetBindings(False))
            m_mreSeriesManfSet.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
            If m_oc_tDSR IsNot Nothing Then RemoveHandler m_oc_tDSR.CollectionChanged, AddressOf m_oc_tDSR_CollectionChanged
            'Debug.Print(m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.Local.ToString)
            'Debug.Print(m_CurrentSeries)
            'Debug.Print(m_CurrentManufacturer)
            m_oc_tDSR = New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction)(From tDSR As tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction In m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.Local
                                                                                                    Where (tDSR.AUS_SRS_CD = m_CurrentSeries And tDSR.ManufacturerID = m_CurrentManufacturer)
                                                                                                    Select tDSR)
            DoDBContextAction(DBActivityType.Downloading, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), False, {True}, Sub()
                                                                                                       bs_tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.DataSource = m_oc_tDSR
                                                                                                       bs_tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.ResetBindings(False)
                                                                                                   End Sub)
            AddHandler m_oc_tDSR.CollectionChanged, AddressOf m_oc_tDSR_CollectionChanged
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function DoDBContextAction(ActivityType As DBActivityType, Timeout As TimeSpan?, DoLock As Boolean, DoInvoke() As Boolean, ParamArray Action() As Action)
        Dim Saved As Boolean = False, XLoadingBlocked As Boolean = False
        If DoInvoke.Length <> Action.Length Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("The number of elements in the DoInvoke() and Action() arrays must be the same.", "DoInvoke, Action")
        End If
        Do
            If Not DoLock Then
                For Ctr As Integer = 0 To Action.GetUpperBound(0)
                    If DoInvoke(Ctr) And Me.InvokeRequired Then
                        Me.Invoke(Action(Ctr))
                    Else
                        Action(Ctr)()
                    End If
                Next
                Saved = True
            ElseIf Monitor.TryEnter(m_oDataContextLock, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)) Then
                If XLoadingBlocked Then
                    ' ...
                    XLoadingBlocked = False
                    ' ...
                End If
                Try
                    For Ctr As Integer = 0 To Action.GetUpperBound(0)
                        If DoInvoke(Ctr) And Me.InvokeRequired Then
                            Me.Invoke(Action(Ctr))
                        Else
                            Action(Ctr)()
                        End If
                    Next
                    Saved = True
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw
                Finally
                    Monitor.Exit(m_oDataContextLock)
                End Try
            Else
                If Not XLoadingBlocked Then
                    ' ...
                    XLoadingBlocked = True
                    ' ...
                End If
                Thread.Yield()
            End If
        Loop Until Saved Or (Timeout.HasValue AndAlso DateTime.Now - StartTime > Timeout.Value)
        ' ...
        Return Saved
    End Function

    Private Sub frm_OrderMatching_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Load Data...
        m_Context = New ForeContext
        With m_Context
            .Database.Log = Sub(S As String) Debug.WriteLine(S)
            .Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
            Dim ConnStr As String = My.Settings.ConnectionString & ";multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"
            With .Database.Connection
                If .ConnectionString <> ConnStr Or .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    If .State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                        .Close()
                    End If
                    .ConnectionString = ConnStr
                    .Open()
                End If
            End With
        End With
        AddHandler DirectCast(m_Context, Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.SavingChanges, AddressOf ObjectContext_SavingChanges
        m_CTS = New CancellationTokenSource
        m_tsScheduler = New LimitedConcurrencyReprioritizableTaskScheduler(4)
        m_lTaskList = New List(Of Task)
        m_tLoadManufacturers = New Task(AddressOf LoadManufacturersTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadCrossBorder = New Task(AddressOf LoadCrossBorderTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadDistributionStockModyrsPermitted = New Task(AddressOf LoadDistributionStockModyrsPermittedTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadSeriesManufacturer = New Task(AddressOf LoadSeriesManufacturerTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadDistributionOrdersPermittedEvent = New Task(AddressOf LoadDistributionOrdersPermittedEventsTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadDistributionStockPermittedEvents = New task(AddressOf LoadDistributionStockPermittedEventsTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadLayers = New Task(AddressOf LoadLayersTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadDistributionSeriesManufacturersLayers = New Task(AddressOf LoadDistributionSeriesManufacturersLayersTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadDistributionOrdersRestriction = New Task(AddressOf LoadDistributionOrdersRestrictionTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadDistributionStockRestriction = New Task(AddressOf LoadDistributionStockRestrictionTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadFAWModel = New Task(AddressOf LoadFAWModelTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadPrimaryDealerGroup = New Task(AddressOf LoadPrimaryDealerGroupTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadModelCodes = New Task(AddressOf LoadModelCodesTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tLoadMatchedOrdersTask = New Task(AddressOf LoadMatchedOrdersTask, m_CTS.Token)
        m_tChangeDMOAFilterTask = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll({m_tLoadSeriesManufacturer, m_tLoadPrimaryDealerGroup}, AddressOf ChangeDMOAFilterTask, m_CTS.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, m_tsScheduler)
        m_tChangeFMFilterTask = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll({m_tLoadSeriesManufacturer, m_tLoadFAWModel, m_tLoadModelCodes}, AddressOf ChangeFMFilterTask, m_CTS.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, m_tsScheduler)
        m_lTaskList.AddRange({m_tLoadLayers, m_tLoadManufacturers, m_tLoadCrossBorder, m_tLoadSeriesManufacturer, m_tLoadDistributionOrdersPermittedEvent, m_tLoadDistributionStockPermittedEvents, m_tLoadFAWModel, m_tLoadDistributionStockModyrsPermitted, _
                              m_tLoadDistributionOrdersRestriction, m_tLoadDistributionStockRestriction, m_tLoadPrimaryDealerGroup, m_tLoadModelCodes, m_tLoadMatchedOrdersTask, m_tChangeFMFilterTask})
        m_tLoadComplete = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(m_lTaskList.ToArray, AddressOf LoadCompleteTask, m_CTS.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, m_tsScheduler)

        m_tLoadManufacturers.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadCrossBorder.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadDistributionStockModyrsPermitted.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadSeriesManufacturer.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadDistributionOrdersPermittedEvent.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadDistributionStockPermittedEvents.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadLayers.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadDistributionSeriesManufacturersLayers.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadDistributionOrdersRestriction.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadDistributionStockRestriction.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadFAWModel.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadPrimaryDealerGroup.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadModelCodes.Start(m_tsScheduler)
        m_tLoadMatchedOrdersTask.Start(m_tsScheduler)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I intermittently get a `NullReferenceException`, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in `LoadDistributionStockRestrictionTask` on the line beginning `m_oc_tDSR = New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction)(...`.  This error occurs perhaps one in ten runs, and when debugging, if I edit, change nothing, then run again, the error never re-occurs.

The stack trace is:

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.PerformAdd(IList`1 entries)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AlignChangesInRelationships(IList`1 entries)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Local()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.get_Local()
   at ForeNET.frm_OrderMatching.LoadDistributionStockRestrictionTask() in C:\Users\jzg48k\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Fore GUI\Fore .NET\Forms\frm_OrderMatching.vb:line 1450
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

The line `Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray, m_CTS.Token)` in `LoadDistributionStockRestrictionTask` ensures that loading dependent entities completes and that `m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.Local`, `m_CurrentSeries` and `m_CurrentManufacturer` have valid values.  The Debug.Print lines above the line in question show that this is always the case when this error occurs.

Can anyone suggest a solution.

Comment: Where does `m_Context` get instantiated?

Comment: As an aside, your VB .Net is pretty hard to read.  Line breaks are your friend.  Hungarian Notation is not, according to the Microsoft .Net coding conventions.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin, I've added code to show where `m_Context` gets instantiated.  Sorry about the readability or lack thereof.

Comment: When you set breakpoints, what exactly is null ("Nothing")?

Comment: @DouglasBarbin, I don't know how to find out exactly what variable is unexpectedly `Nothing`.  If I single-step over or step into the LINQ, then the error *never* happens.  The three `Debug.Print` statements above always result in correct values (i.e. not `Nothing`) being output even when an error occurs.  If I don't single-step, then I can't examine the internal LINQ variables.